# Drupal 8 cannot install modules - FTP access is required error

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-14.04, drupal-8

Got completely screwed up and badly needing your suggestion. I am trying  to install a new module but getting a whole bunch of error. The last message says `Installing modules and themes requires FTP access to your server.` I installed FTP server using `$ sudo apt-get install vsftpd`.

Updated `vsftpd.conf` by uncommenting the following lines:

```
listen=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
```

And finally added the following line:

```
local_root=/home
```

Restarted the service `$ sudo service vsftpd restart`. Went back to module install page, tried but the same error comes back.

What I am missing? Referred to  https://www.drupal.org/node/1608658

**UPDATE**:

On my `phpinfo();` page I can see the following under **Configure Command** column:

```
'--enable-ftp' '--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2'
```